# Element is not visible with Splinter (Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, automation, splinter, chrome-web-driver

After filling a form I am trying to click the following submit button:

```
<div class="tl_formbody_submit">
   <div class="tl_submit_container">
     <input type="submit" class="tl_submit" value="Einstellungen speichern" onclick="Backend.getScrollOffset()">
</div>
```

The code is:

```
browser.find_by_xpath('//input[@class="tl_submit"]').click()
```

The stacktrace says, that the element is not visible - but why?

Thanks!

Comment: provide python code

Comment: Maybe try a wait function before, see if that makes a difference

Comment: because the element is not visible. how about putting some wait before this line.

Answer (score 1):

```
# import options 
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# desired url link 
URL = 'www.path.com'

#driver & settings 
driver = webdriver.Chrome('PATH TO CHROMEDRIVER.EXE')
driver.get('URL')
driver.delete_all_cookies

#find element & click 
driver.find_element_by_id("Einstellungen speichern").click()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

if the stacktrace says element is not visible, if means it's not visible when you are trying to find it.

may be some action requires to make it visible (some ajax request) or may be you just need to wait a while before you click it.

you could use explicit wait as mentioned below.

```
submit_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='tl_submit']")))
submit_button.click()
```

Comment: Waited 10 seconds and it does not work, too. The form are database credentials (https://download.contao.org/3.5.28/zip).

Comment: increase the timeout.

Comment: Not working... :/ Think waiting is not the solution and it requires a special "hack"...

Comment: https://github.com/contao/core/blob/549738f9a41974d963bd09a3a83ae0f46f887f01/system/modules/core/templates/backend/be_install.html5 this is the install file

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason for the element to be 'not visible' is due to the error in assigning the xpath. Best way is to copy the xpath from the html (inspect element) and paste it. It works for most of the cases, try it.

You can check the link below, I had got a similar problem too, the possible solution can be here but for me the above-mentioned solution was fine. 
[How to fix "Element not interactable" Selenium error in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57651075/how-to-fix-element-not-interactable-selenium-error-in-python?noredirect=1#comment101757065_57651075)

Comment: Try to explain what's the link you wrote in your answer.

Comment: @MohamadShahrestani I had got a similar problem and the solutions might be found there. The correct answer in my case is also mentioned above.