# How to fix "Element not interactable" Selenium error in Python?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium

I was trying to click a popup button and my code shows the error:

> "selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable".

I have searched but could not find the solution which works for me with the popup buttons.

[Image for clicking show 10 rows and displaying the pop-up box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjEdo.png)The attached image is the desired result and 'Show 10 rows' is behind it and lightly seen.

I have this in my HTML code and need to click on the button.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" id="loadsur" href="#Section" aria-expanded="true">LoadSurvey</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-left: -10px;">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <div id="myDataTable25_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper no-footer"><div class="dt-buttons">
                <button class="dt-button buttons-csv buttons-html5" tabindex="0" aria-controls="myDataTable25">
                   <span>Csv</span></button> 
                <button class="dt-button buttons-excel buttons-html5" tabindex="0" aria-controls="myDataTable25">
                   <span>Excel</span></button> 
                <button class="dt-button buttons-collection buttons-page-length" tabindex="0" aria-controls="myDataTable25" aria-haspopup="true">
                   <span>Show 10 rows</span></button> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In Python I tried this:

```
def single_meter(i=0):
browser=webdriver.Chrome('C:\Webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
for row in range (5,10):
    browser.get('http://#link'+consumer_ID+'?reportrange=21%2F07%2F2018-25%2F08%2F2019')
        Show10 = find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='dt-button buttons-collection buttons-page-length']//span[contains(text(),'Show 10 rows')]")
    Show10.click()
```

I expect to click this button which causes a popup button to appear.

Comment: `span` is not `button` even if it looks like button and it can't be clicked. You have to find `button` and click it.

Comment: I tried it with button too but the same error message arises. Any further suggestions please.

Comment: Is there an `iframe` in the HTML?

Comment: @MosheSlavin there is iframe at the end only only this much <iframe src="chrome-extension://kdfieneakcjfaiglcfcgkidlkmlijjnh/writer/index.html" __idm_frm__="498"></iframe>

Comment: @MosheSlavin The attached image is the desired result and 'Show 10 rows' is behind it and lightly seen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a solution to this problem. The error was with the link in the xpath. I later copied and pasted from the html and the code now looks this:

```
Show10 = find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='myDataTable2_wrapper']/div[1]/button[7]/span")
Show10.click()
```

And it works fine. Thank all for your help.

Answer (score 3):

It might be in an `iframe`.

Try first to find the iframe and switch to it.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("http:/link") 
frame_id = 'frame'
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, frame_id)))
```

Then try clicking on the button.

```
Show10 = wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='dt-button buttons-collection buttons-page-length']//span[contains(text(),'Show 10 rows')]")))
Show10.click()
```

Comment: @ Moshe Slavin One thing what must be singlemeter, is it correct: singlemeter=browser.get("http:/link) and browser=webdriver.chrome() ??

Comment: @AbanishTiwari I don't see a reason to put the `get` in a variable. `get()` navigates to a url but it is not the webdriver

Comment: @AbanishTiwari you can try the Moshe Slavin suggest, it may inside iframe, or please post more the code, we'll try solve your issue.

Comment: @Moshe Slavin Thank you, I later realized assigning .get () to a variable is not necessary. I run as per the change mentioned above, but it raises an error:  ::::::::::::::    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message :   ::::::::What might  be the reason it is not it able to find the element?

Comment: @farianH I had tried it.  Ok I will send you more codes.

Comment: @AbanishTiwari you can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57651075/edit) with the relevant HTML

Comment: @MosheSlavin Please find the code above and I have attached the HTML in the same text along with the image.

Comment: @MosheSlavin Please view it. I am not able to click any of them.  Copy, csv, excel, Show 10 rows.........any

Answer (score 1):

Change the `xpath` with :

```
//button[@class='dt-button buttons-collection buttons-page-length']//span[contains(text(),'Show 10 rows')]
```

Try use `WebDriverWait` for make sure the element exist, and add `expected_conditions` until the element `clickable`.

Import this :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
```

Try this :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(singlemeter, 10)
Show10 = wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='dt-button buttons-collection buttons-page-length']//span[contains(text(),'Show 10 rows')]")))
Show10.click()
```

Or use `ActionChains`, import this :

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
```

Try this :

```
ActionChains(singlemeter).move_to_element(Show10).click(Show10).perform()
```

Comment: I edited and changed to this::::::: wait = WebDriverWait(singlemeter, 10) Show10 = wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@class='dt-button buttons-collection buttons-page-length']//span[contains(text(),'Show 10 rows')]"))) Show10.click() :::::::::::: But it could not find raises the error "selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: "

Comment: `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:` this is error because element not found within the specified time period

Comment: Is this the correct way to use actionchain? :::::: wait = WebDriverWait(singlemeter, 10)
        Show10 = wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@class='dt-button buttons-collection buttons-page-length']//span[contains(text(),'Show 10 rows')]")))
        ActionChains(load_survey).move_to_element(Show10).click(Show10).perform()::::::::: I am new to actionChains. This didn;t worked for me.

Comment: @AbanishTiwari `ActionChains` excepts the driver... in your case, you called it `singlemeter` so use: `ActionChains(singlemeter).move_to_element(Show10).click(Show10).perform()` as showen in the answer!

Comment: Good answer! combining both `WebDriverWait` and `ActionChains` should do the trick!

Comment: @MosheSlavin Sorry, I don't know the reason but the element could not be found, the time is 10 s. It is fine when I click manually. One thing what must be singlemeter, is it correct: singlemeter=browser.get("http:/link) and browser=webdriver.chrome() ??