# Using Selenium to accept a splash page

Tags: python, selenium

When I load the my site as shown below, a splash screen appears to confirm I am 21 years of age. I am trying to load the element to click yes, but I am unable to bypass the age verification screen.

My approach was to load the page. Add a sleep time, find the element and click Yes. However it wont work.

```
driver.get('https://seelbachs.com/products/sagamore-spirit-cask-strength-rye-whiskey')

time.sleep(5)

element= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="enter"]')

element.click()
```

Error received.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="enter"]"}
```

So either my find.element is off or my time.sleep is not helping with the splash page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem is that the pop-up is in an iframe.

This code appears to do the trick

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC   
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://seelbachs.com/products/sagamore-spirit-cask-strength-rye-whiskey')

# xpath of iframe
frame_xpath = '/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div/div/iframe'
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
# wait until iframe appears and select iframe
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, frame_xpath)))

# select button
xpath = '//*[@id="enter"]'
time.sleep(2)
element= driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click(element).perform()
```

referencing [This answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57652869/15755316)

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch to the frame, check the below code

```
driver.get('https://seelbachs.com/products/sagamore-spirit-cask-strength-rye-whiskey')

sleep(5)
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@id,'fancyboxAge-frame')]"))

OR 
#Using the explicitWait
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[contains(@id,'fancyboxAge-frame')]")))

element= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="enter"]')
element.click()
```

**import**

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import  webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply however, neither option selected the "Yes" on the age verification screen.

`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="enter"]"}`